# Can someone please explain me the code for the hashmap get(key) method?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Inside the get(Object key) method of Java , there is a piece of code which I am not able to understand.

I know how the get(key) method works even in case when hashcode is same for two object.

But the below piece of code I am unable to understand.

```
for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
              e != null;
              e = e.next) {
             Object k;
             if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
                 return e.value;
         }
```

Can someone explain.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` works with [Hash bucket algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). And Hash buckets are arranged as array which the `HashMap` class calls as `table`. So the `for` loop starts with the first element of the hash bucket which holds the `key`

```
Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)
```

here the `hash` represents the **hash index** of that bucket

---

`for` loop will run till there are elements in the bucket (`e != null`)

---

`for` loop will iterate like  `e = e.next` , that is, moving to next element in the bucket until match is found

---

Now, once the hash bucket is found, the method should return the exact Entry whose key matches the passed `key`. Now this matching is done by either **references matching** ( `==` ) or **equals matching**  `(k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)`

if the matching happens then the key is returned else the method will return `null`